# Align custom push button on delivered PeopleSoft Fluid page

Tags: fluid, peoplesoft

We need to add a custom button named COPY_BUTTON to a delivered PeopleSoft fluid page. We added it to the group box next to an edit box but it is listed below and to the left of the page. How do we align it right of the edit box? I’m very new to Fluid so any help would be very appreciative.

We have tried applying custom css however when the page changes, the push button does not move with the edit box.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.